# IdentityServer4 вопрос необходимости

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, protocol, identityserver4

я тут недавно начал пытаться разобраться в IdentityServer. Так сложилось чтоя по работал на не скольких проектов, но почти всегда IdentityServer уже был настроен. Решил разобраться в нем самостоятельно дома. 
Входе выяснение узнал про такие вещи как **oauth 2.0** и **openId**.

**Oauth 2.0** -это протокол позволяющий нашему приложение получать токен от других приложение(facebook, twiter,vk и т.д) при том делать это без передачи пароля и логина нашему приложению

**OpenId** - позволяет этот самый токен переиспользовать в других приложениях без надобности повторного ввода пароля.

Т.е по сути IdentityServer4 нужен что бы просто логиниться в сторонних приложениях, но во всех проектах что я до этого встречал IdentityServer4 использовали что бы  лосниться просто в текущем приложении без получения  токена от всяких сторонних. **Какой же в этом смысл?** Может быть я чего то не понимаю ? Все приложения были написаны на asp.net core. При том что проект занимающийся авторизацией, является **микросервисом**

Comment: Если вам надо хранить логины только для вашего приложения и больше ни для кого, и авторизоваться только в вашем приложении, то делать для этого отдельный сервер авторизации нет никакого смысла.

Comment: а если речь идет об микросервисной архитектуре?

Comment: то об этом писать надо в вопросе

Comment: понял сейчас подправлю, просто мне  казалось сейчас микросервисы везде,такой параметр по умолчанию

Comment: @tym32167 так а вы понимаете зачем это нужно в микросервисах, не мог ли бы вы мне объяснить?

Comment: я подправил описание своего вопроса

Comment: в микросервисах каждый микросервис - отдельное приложение. То есть если юзеру был выдан токен от IdentityServer, то этот юзер с этим токеном может обратиться к любому доступному ему сервису. То есть получается в микросервисах будем иметь много приложений и одну точку аутентификации - IdentityServer, вместо того, чтобы логиниться на каждый микросервис отдельно.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, у меня подобные мысли были но я не был уверен, если перенести комментарий в ответы, выставлю это как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл в микросервисах - разделение ответственности.

Один сервис занимается мониторингом, другой - конфигурациями, третий - логгированием, четвертый - аутентификацией, и т.д.

В микросервисах каждый микросервис - отдельное приложение. То есть если юзеру был выдан токен от IdentityServer, то этот юзер с этим токеном может обратиться к любому доступному ему сервису. То есть получается в микросервисах будем иметь много приложений и одну точку аутентификации - IdentityServer, вместо того, чтобы логиниться на каждый микросервис отдельно.