# Как работает security в микросервисной архитектуре?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, микросервисы

Делаю проект с микоросервисной архитектурой. И не совсем понятно как должна работать авторизация. У меня есть сервис gateway и сервис security. На форумах пишут что должно работать так... security отдаёт JWT. Пользователь делает запрос с JWT на gateway, а он должен проверить JWT в сервисе security. Но в примерах делают проверку JWT в сервисе gateway и не обращается к security. Получается на словах одно, а на практике другое. Может кто подсказать как должно работать? Как должна быть авторизация jwt? и как с авторизацией должны работать сервисы между собой? сейчас они напрямую делают запросы, а не через gateway.

Comment: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1007058/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1136025/179763)

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо. теперь понял как должно работать.